# Scraping historic data with Python from a specific website - table created out of a form with many rows with isolated header. Automation needed

Tags: python, html, forms, web-scraping, datatables

I am trying to do some data scraping from this website: http://www.meteoprog.sk/sk/fwarchive/Bratislava/

I am essentially looking for monthly weather data (30 dni a noci) from Jan 2012 till Dec 2013. I would like to automate the scraping and save the data in a txt or cvs file.

However, it looks like there is something wrong with the way the table is compiled - my Google Chrome scraper won't pick it up.

I wrote my code to see what data I can get from the table:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'http://www.meteoprog.sk/sk/fwarchive/Bratislava/'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content

soup=BeautifulSoup(html)
table = soup.find("table",attrs={"class":"fwtab"})

for row in table.findAll("tr"):
    print table
```

The numeric values are not showing and this seems to be only picking up the values in the header. 
Is there any easy way to automate the scraping from this web or any form queried web for that matter?

Any help is very much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Following the link you posted leads me to a page with a table header and no actual contents. I tried playing with the dates and options but wasn't able to produce a table with any actual contents...

Comment: Same here. Even so it seems that the content is static. If you want to do it once I would recommend to play with the Scraper extensions for Chrome. Otherwise I generally prefer Selenium for scraping sites with submission forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#_*_coding: utf-8_*_
import requests
import BeautifulSoup as bs
import csv
import calendar as cal
import datetime as dt

url = 'http://www.meteoprog.sk/sk/fwarchive/Bratislava/'
```

This service requires POST data in this format `{'data': '2012-01-31', 'days': '30', 'search': u'Hľadanie' }` to get data for Jan, 2012. Here I build POST request data in the format for every month in 2012 and 2013.

```
years = (2012, 2013)
months = range(1,13)
data = {'search': u'Hľadanie'}
for y in years:
        for m in months:
                days = cal.monthrange(y,m)[1]
                data['days'] = str(days - 1)
                data['data'] = dt.date(y,m,days).isoformat()
```

`cal.monthrange` returns a tuple of weekday and number of days in the month for the given month and year. I use the number of days as the last day of the month value in `dt.date` call to get date in '2012-01-31' format and to calculate the 'days' value for POST data.

```
                response = requests.post(url,data=data)
                html = response.content

                soup=bs.BeautifulSoup(html)
                table = soup.find("table",attrs={"class":"fwtab"})

                list_of_rows=[]
                hr = table.find('tr')
                hr.extract()
```

Because the table contains a header row, the `hr = table.find('tr');hr.extract()` remove it from the table.

```
                for row in table.findAll('tr'):
                    list_of_cells = []
                    for cell in row.findAll('td'):
                        text = cell.text.replace('&nbsp;', '')
                        text = text.encode('utf-8')
                        list_of_cells.append(text)
                    list_of_rows.append(list_of_cells)

                list_of_rows.reverse()
```

The table has recent values first. So make it chronological, I reverse the list.

```
                otptfile = open("./meteo.csv", "ab")
                writer = csv.writer(otptfile)
                writer.writerows(list_of_rows)
                print 'data stored for %s, %s' % (m,y)
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you! Would you maybe have a recommendation for how to isolate a table from the "soup"?

Comment: I guess one thing I would like to add is to add lines to it that will make all the dates (1/1/2012 - 12/31/2013) save in the meteo.csv file. is that possible? Thanks!